# What the Apple's new iPad Pro site canvas animation technique?

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, webgl, rendering

Apple's iPad Pro website has a unique way of using image sources for sequence animations. In the Chrome Devtool, you can find this technique.

[image]

I've been researching for this technique, but I couldn't find any information. Can anyone tell me what technique they are using?

https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/

[image]

Comment: Where's the animation?

Comment: You can find in 
https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/

Comment: That's a web page. I visited it already, but don't see anything that stands out.

Comment: Apple website didn't show animation and interaction according to nation or browsing env.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question, code included. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm asking whats this collage technique, instead of using bunch of sequence images

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210559/discussion-between-retriever-and-stackslave).

Comment: It's a bunch of `picture` elements just being shown and hidden when you're scrolling, nothing fancy or unique.

Comment: @Teemu I know canvas sequence animation. I just asking rendering way this collage image source.

Comment: There's no canvas, the animation consists of [picture elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture) and a simple onscroll event. Unless the animation is created with a totally different technique in iPads ..?

Comment: No, you can find here... http://snpy.in/zzaxX4

Comment: @Retriever and the code is in `overview.built.js` look for `glCanvas`

Comment: @Teemu as far as I can tell, it depends on the resolution. As soon as I shrink the browser window, I only see static images and the animation doesn't come back untill I reload the page with the browser window being pretty much fullscreen.

Comment: Thx @Thomas, I knew the function in WebGL. But I wonder how can make the sources(like collage, striped) what is the rendering tech.

Comment: Agreed with retriever, I'd like to understand how this is achieved.
This technique involves assets but also code to display it properly.
For this reason, the question is legit.

Comment: @griable Fianlly someone who understands this question!!